# How to let a fixed "sticky" div stay outside the viewport

Tags: jquery, scroll, positioning, sticky

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/.

The problem is that whenever the fixed positioning is applied to the div, if the browser width gets changed the div moves horizontally to fit inside the viewport. In the tutorial example http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html this does not happen.

This is my code (everything is inside a relative-positioned #wrapper):

CSS:

```
        #cart {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            width: 270px;
        }

        #target {
            width: 270px;
            height: 200px;

            background-color: blue;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;

            position: absolute;
            top: 250px;
            right: 0;

            padding: 0;
            border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0 ;
        }

        #drag-here {
            width: 270px;
            height: 0;

            background-image: url(drag-here.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: none;

            position: absolute;
            top: 470px;
            right: 0;
        }

        #cart-list {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 430px;
            right: 0;

            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .sticky #target {position: fixed; top: 5px;}
        .sticky #drag-here {position: fixed; top: 225px;}
        .sticky #cart-list {position: fixed; top: 185px;}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="cart">
    <div id="target" class="target-listen"></div>
    <div id="drag-here"></div>
    <ul id="cart-list">
    </ul>
</section>
```

JQuery:

```
sticky = false;
initialOffset = $("#target").offset().top - 5;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= initialOffset) {
        if (!sticky) {
            $("#cart").addClass("sticky");
            sticky = true;
        } 
    }
    else {
        if (sticky) {
            $("#cart").removeClass("sticky");
            sticky = false;
        }
    }
});
```

You can see my page here: http://www.brandcoffee.it/test/brandapart/imagick.php

Comment: if you want it outside the viewport you want to use a container element. set a fixed width for the viewport like 1000px. if the viewport is now only 800px wide the rest 200px gets cut. and its including your sticky thing if its on the right side of your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removing `right : 0;` in `#target` should do.

Comment: And it did! I had to remove the right : 0; in all the siblings div as well. Still the <ul> is not aligning properly.

Comment: Ok, seems like it was an inline/block problem. I replaced <ul> and <li>s with divs and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try with providing the `width` attribute in `ratio` (or percent) rather than fixed pixel values.
such as :

```
width:25%; //for #target, and
float:right; //make target float right

width:75%; // for other contents on left side
```